# How to focus marker maps in jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps-markers, jquery-tabs

I have a problem before ask in here, i already searching in google or cases in stackoverflow, but not solved this case :(

This is my screnshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSIsS.png
sign red arrow this is place marker, why google maps not focus in place marker ?

and this mycode

this part code **page.php**

```
<div id="tab-5">

                   <?php 
                    $map = "-6.3447213,106.8658161";
                    $title = "Creative School";
                    $image = "log.jpg";
                    $addres = "DKI JAKARTA";
                    ?>
                     <iframe id="headerMap" width="480" HEIGHT="420"></iframe>
                     <script>
                    jQuery("iframe#headerMap").attr("src", "map.php?map=<?php echo $map;?>&title=<?php echo $title ?>&image=<?php echo $image ?>&addres=<?php echo $addres ?>"); 
                    </script>

                    </div>
```

this full code **map.php**

```
<style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
var map;
var TILE_SIZE = 256;
var lang = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_GET['map'];?>);

function createInfoWindowContent() {

  return [
    '<center><b><?php echo $_GET['title'];?></b></center>',
    '<center><b><?php echo $_GET['addres'];?></b></center>',
    '<center><img src="images/<?php echo $_GET['image'];?>"></center>'
  ].join('<br>');
}

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: lang
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  coordInfoWindow.setContent(createInfoWindowContent());
  coordInfoWindow.setPosition(lang);
  coordInfoWindow.open(map);


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Help me thank's you